# SWFObject placeholder image size

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

is there a way to specify the size of the image placeholder with SWFObject?

Basically I want to scale up the size of the image in flashvars.

```
var flashvars = {
        'file': '<% Response.Write(VideoURL); %>',
        'autostart': 'false',
        'image': '<% Response.Write(Image); %>',
        'screencolor': '#FFFFFF'
    };
    var params = {
        'allowfullscreen': 'true',
        'allowscriptaccess': 'always',
        'bgcolor': '#FFFFFF',
        'wmode': 'opaque'
    };
    var attributes = {
        'id': 'player1',
        'name': 'player1'
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF('../player-licensed.swf', 'flash', '580', '350', '9', 'false', flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Thanks

EDIT: No one knows if this is doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the answer:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/6201/start-player-in-stretching-uniform

needed to add: 'stretching': 'exactfit'